# Sending scheduled reminders in civicase

Tags: scheduled-reminders, civicase

I am trying to set up a scheduled reminder from an activity in Civicase.

The options in scheduled reminders are these:

[image: Recipient options]

I presume what I need to do is send reminders to "Activity Assignees" - that is, the person who whom the case is assigned.

However, in Civicase, I cannot find a way of automatically allocating the "assigned to" field during the set up:

[image: Assigned to]

I can insert this manually, and then reminders work. I am not sure if I choose "Select Group" in scheduled reminders whether this would send a reminder to the whole group of case workers, or just the person dealing with that particular case.